# Python Flask WTForm Email validation does not allow a dash

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm looking to validate an email input field for a user in Flask. I'm currently using WTForms Email validation, but this does not allow the user to input a dash as part of their email address. My code is below:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
```

How can I allow a dash in the email address but still protect against malicious inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You must replace `Email` validator by `Regexp` for validating [special email patterns](https://regexr.com/3e48o):

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Regexp

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(
        'Email',
        validators=[DataRequired(), Regexp(r"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$")]
    )
```

Comment: Just one thing: I had to modify your regex slightly to comply with what Python expects and to allow for the + sign: 
`r"^[-\w\.\+]+@([-\w]+\.)+[-\w\ ]{2,4}$"` Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: I think plus sign is not valid for emails, whoever you can use every pattern that you need

Comment: the plus sign is valid and very useful if you need a second account - I use it all the time, for example my_address@gmail.com and my_address+potential_spam@gmail.com will both go to the same inbox. Also Python complains (I'm not sure why) if the dash is last, which is why I set it before the `\w` in my proposed regex.

Comment: Okay, use this pattern, about dash in regex brackets and when use between two characters meaning range of characters, for sample `[a-d]` is equal to `[abcd]`